# Send multiple analog signals to PC audio input

Tags: audio, data, sampling

I have 4 signals that I need to send to the PC through the audio jack. Is there a way to do so with minimum data losses? I can't use frequency division multiplexing, so I need a way to get the 4 signals to be sent serially in order to record it using the mic, and extract each separate signal.

Is that doable? If yes how?

Comment: Yes, it's doable.

Comment: can you give me a suggestion as to how? @Andyaka

Comment: What is the bandwidth of your signals?

Comment: Ditto what RoyC says and you need to explain why FDM can't be done.

Comment: Digital analog?

Comment: analog signals, frequency 0-5 Hz, I tried FDM with both AM and FM modulation, the recorder doesn't quit capture the AM or the FM signal (its kind of deformed). FDM was my first choice but then my adviser suggested not using that, what he suggested was using time domain, capturing 10ms intervals and plotting them (matlab). of course in order to use this, an analog multiplexer will be used to select the channels and pass them to the pc.

Comment: The signals are constant or only slowly changing so that switching between them isn't an issue? This is for a lab project? In that case I'd say go low tech and use two DPDT relays in series, that will let you select which of the 4 signals is connected to the input.

Comment: no they are constant (heartbeats) and this not a course project, it's big a research project, and I'm working on a part of it.

Comment: You do know there typically is a DC-blocking cap at the input of sound cards, right? And, if it is a big research project, can't you afford a resonably priced capture device with real analog inputs? A sound input really isn't very appropriate for this.

Comment: I know, but it's an application for developing countires, so we have to make it as cheap as possible, eventually, a phone will be used instead of a pc.

Answer (score 3):

Getting a little off the question here but I think we have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) situation here.

Going by the comments you don't need to get 4 analog signals into the audio input of a PC.
What you need to do is get 4 analog signals into a PC/phone as cheaply as possible.

That is a very different problem.

For the price of a 4 input analog multiplexer and the electronics to switch between the inputs at the appropriate rate you could probably get a small micro controller with 4 analog inputs. This would allow you to sample all 4 signals constantly at a sufficient rate and then transfer that data to the PC/phone over USB.
It has the added advantage that unlike the microphone socket the USB socket would also be able to supply plenty of power to run the external electronics.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried doing it with a usb, reading 4 sensors directly (serial communication). My controller was arduino, I managed to plot the 4 sensors successfully. For some reason my supervisor wants it via the audio jack (even though I told him it's more robust and we won't loose any data). The final thought of today is to use an arduino to generate the control signals for the mux and once a serial stream is passed to the pc, we can take segments from it (lets say each channel has 500 samples) then add it to the channel's vector on matlab and plot it. I'll try that and see what happens.

Comment: I'd say go with an ARM M0 based CPU. Something like an LPC11Uxx part with at least 4 analog inputs. They can be as cheap as $2.50, will give you far more CPU power than an arduino so you can sample faster and have USB built in so there is no USB/serial converter needed to get it into a phone.

Comment: Absolutely right. This has to be the way to go. +1

Answer (score 1):

Broadly use an analog switch multiplexer to select channel (time division multiplexing). You have to bear in mind that the sound card input will be AC coupled so measuring instantaneous values does not work. If you can convert the output level of the multiplexer to a high frequency AC value (amplitude modulation) you can then measure the AC amplitude in the sound card giving you the instantaneous value for each channel.

Comment: I tried reading a single channel (heartbeat) and I could see it clearly. I was using audacity, and I saw several similar approaches online. For the AM modulation, I tried it(with a sine wave), the AM signal will be clear on my oscilloscope, but as soon as I connect it to the pc (via AUX), is gets deformed (it becomes a very noisy or bold msg signal).

Comment: What frequency was your AM signal and what is your sound card sampling rate?

Comment: the sound card's sampling rate was 1000Hz, my msg signal was 3 Hz (sine) and my carrier was 500 Hz.

Comment: That should be ok but the higher the sampling rate the better your sound card should go to at least 44kHz. Also check that your signal level to the audio input is not to high.

Comment: yes both msg and carrier are 0.5vpp, I'll try with a higher sampling rate

Comment: somehow I'm no able to sucessfully record an AM signal, but when I demodulate it using simulink's demodulation blocks, I get a giant sine wave that has a frequency of 0.1 Hz (which is not my msg signal).

Answer (score 1):

Multiple signals into one channel means Multiplexing.

There are several types of multiplexing that people have invented over the last, ooh, century or so. Generally it's quite easy to stuff several signals down into one channel, the more difficult bit is recovering the separate signals afterwards.

If you have a PC sound card, and 4 heart-rate bandwidth channels, then there's bags of excess capacity, which means you can be quite lazy about how you decode the signals (in communications, bandwidth is expensive, so we work hard at the encoding and decoding to stuff as much data down any given channel as possible).

Time division multiplex is conceptually easy, the tricky bit is synchronising the frame so that we can switch each segment to the correct channel. We also need to make sure we end up with a signal that goes through the channel, so if it's a PC audio card, don't introduce DC.

If you can use both stereo channels, then a synchronising tick on one channel is a very simple way to get decoder sync. In order to avoid DC, I'd be inclined to switch each channel in as +ve, then -ve polarity, so the net DC voltage of every channel is zero.

If you must use just one channel, or want to expand capacity later, then an 'in-band' sync method can be used, with a specific level, or shape, or duration of a pulse to signal the start of the multiplex frame.

Frequency division multiplex is also very possible. Use a VCO for each channel, with the signal modulating the frequency. Use the VCOs from 4046s, they are fairly linear and quite tame. Centre one on (say) 1kHz, another at 4kHz, and 2k and 8k on the other channel. Square waves have very low even harmonics, so the filtering is relatively simple, we don't want the harmonics of a low oscillator corrupting the signal of a higher one. Separation and demodulation of the signals doesn't need time synchronisation, but it does need an elementary knowledge of DSP. It should be within the capacity of any reasonable PC to demodulate multiple channels in real time.

Answer (score 1):

I've read what you put and to my way of thinking frequency division multiplexing is the best way.

> the sound card's sampling rate was 1000Hz, my msg signal was 3 Hz
>   (sine) and my carrier was 500 Hz. – Isra

Then this is why you have problems. If you are sampling at 1000 Hz and your carrier is 500 Hz you have a potential (if not actual) aliasing problem. Imagine you are sampling a carrier twice per cycle; you might get this: -

[image]

Or you might get these: -

[image]

How will you know which original waveform you are sampling if you sample bang-on the nyquist rate - do your self a favour and sample at least 3 times the rate.

This is why frequency division multiplexing isn't working for you.

> yes both msg and carrier are 0.5vpp

Make life easier for yourself and add a dc offset so that you get a modulation that is easier to decode: -

[image]

You should be aiming for 50% modulation to make things easier. I will also add that for each signal transmitted you should intersperse 0 volts and a reference voltage but make sure the whole baseband signal remains band limited to a few tens of Hz so that overlap with other channels is avoided.

Comment: Thanks very much! I tried a lower carrier (100 Hz) and I'm now able to recover my msg signal; however with 44.1kHz sampling rate I can't recover it. If I'm going to modulate the 4 channels and have a gap between them (carriers 100 300 500 and 700) my highest frequency will by around 800Hz, so using 1kHz sampling frequency again won't work, correct? I'll keep trying with it, maybe I'm doing something wrong as it should work even with higher sampling frequencies.

Comment: Maybe the device used for demodulating each carrier cannot work with simultaneous carriers present? In other words it only is capable of demodulating one carrier?

Comment: I'm using matlab, it should be able to handle several carriers. What I meant is that with a higher recording sampling rate (44100) in Matlab, I couldn't recover the msg. I was trying a single channel only. This worked with 1000Hz sampling rate and a 100Hz carrier frequency though.

Comment: Also, you mention DC offset, isn't that going to be blocked by the soundcard?

Comment: The DC offset I mentioned is to do with the modulation waveform; once modulated there is not DC offset.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea, if you want that to be as cheap as possible and still use the sound input jack of a PC/mobile phone: why don't you just send *digital* data through the jack?

Given the very low sampling frequency required for your application, you could easily just take the cheapest MCU that has an ADC with 4 analog inputs, and regularily send the four sampled values as a serial stream of bits, at a rate appropriate for the sound input (maybe something like 1kHz).

All you need to have for the protocol is some kind of start bit (or start sequence), and modulate the stream using some very simple scheme like unipolar RZ to circumvent the DC blocking cap. You can make it more robust with 4b/5b and manchester encoding, but I doubt this would be really necessary.

This is easy to generate (you need just one chip and barely any passives), and very easy to analyze on the software PC/phone side (much easier than FM demodulation, or even time-division multiplex which requires some kind of synchronization).

And, since you're worried about data loss: you have complete control over the accuracy of your samples, since the ADC is on your own MCU's side. Just choose one that has the precision you need. But you don't depend on the accuracy of the sound input anymore, and there is minimum analog circuitry.

Comment: This never crossed my mind! I'll learn more about unipolar Rz and give it a try! Thank you very much

Comment: Here is a [link](http://www.rfwireless-world.com/Terminology/RZ-vs-NRZ-vs-manchester-code.html) for the various usual modulation schemes. But really, this would certainly be the simplest. Both from the device circuit design side, and from the software demodulation side.